# How do you give access to several users to one EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

My team has some EC2 instances and we all need SSH access to them. These instances were created with one IAM user and the credentials were assigned to that user. We do have the keys but how are you suppose to give SSH access to those instances to several users?

The only way I have managed to accomplish that is by securely sharing those keys but it feels like it's the wrong way to do it. So, what are the best practices regarding the access to EC2 instances to several users?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the steps covered in the AWS Docs for [managing user accounts on your EC2 instance.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/managing-users.html)

The basic idea here is to add users directly to the instance itself (via `sudo adduser`).

Once each of your users has an account and SSH key stored locally on the EC2 instance, they should be able to SSH into it as expected.

Answer (score 0):

An option might be to create your EC2 instances as part of an [AWS OpsWorks Stack](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/welcome_classic.html).

> AWS OpsWorks is a configuration management service that helps you configure and operate applications in a cloud enterprise by using Puppet or Chef

The advantage of using this is that Opsworks manages SSH key access to instances for multiple users, while allowing each user to manage their own SSH private keys. according to the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/security-ssh-access.html):

> For Linux stacks, AWS OpsWorks Stacks provides a simpler and more flexible way to manage SSH key pairs.
>
> - Each user registers a personal key pair.
>     They store the private key locally and register the public key with AWS OpsWorks Stacks, as described in Registering an IAM User's Public SSH Key.
> - When you set user permissions for a stack, you specify which users should have SSH access to the stack's instances.
>     AWS OpsWorks Stacks automatically creates a system user on the stack's instances for each authorized user and installs their public key. The user can then use the corresponding private key to log in, as described in Logging In with SSH.

Additionally, if you want to convert your existing setup:

> You can also incorporate Linux-based computing resources into a stack that was created outside of AWS OpsWorks Stacks.
>
> - Amazon EC2 instances that you created directly by using the Amazon EC2 console, CLI, or API.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  Note: "AWS OpsWorks Stacks is no longer accepting new customers. Existing customers will be able to use the OpsWorks console, API, CLI, and CloudFormation resources as normal until May 26, 2024, at which time they will be discontinued. To prepare for this transition, we recommend you transition your stacks to AWS Systems Manager as soon as possible. For more information, see AWS OpsWorks Stacks End of Life FAQs and Migrating your AWS OpsWorks Stacks applications to AWS Systems Manager Application Manager."
https://aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/